# Mysterious green overlay on iPad map

Tags: ios, ipad, mapkit

On iPad device and simulator I get a mysterious green overlay on a map and some annotations are missing. Works fine on iPhone. Anyone have this problem? A solution?

[image: Map works on iPhone (left) but obscured on iPad (right)]

Comment: Please show more context for this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overlay looks like your green pin but 100000 times too big[image: bad drawing of how I see the giant pin]

Comment: Lol, really. May be it's a drawing engine glitch.

Comment: May be author enlarges pins somewhere when user clicks them?

Comment: Works fine on iPhone, but hink you are right that the pin image is somehow massive. If I scroll around I can find places where the map is clear. This occurs right as annotations are added. Researching if only green pins!

Comment: The problem was that the pin image for the green pins @2x was huge (typo). Changed to 50x50 and problem resolved.  Thanks!